# Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<> is less accessible than other field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, field

```
[Serializable]
class LotInfo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DonorName { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string RhFactor { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }

    public LotInfo(int id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public LotInfo()
    {

    }
}

[Serializable]
public class LotInfoDatabase
{
    public Dictionary<int, LotInfo> dicLotDatabase = new Dictionary<int, LotInfo>();
    public int LastID { get; set; }
    public int GetNewID()
    {
        return (++LastID);
    }
}
```

Guys, I am doing Serializer for datagridview for saving and loading the data. But this error comes...

Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' is less accessible than field 'Blood_Bank_Management.LotInfoDatabase.dicLotDatabase'

Im new to stackoverflow, please forgive me if I've did any wrong. Thanks...

Comment: Please add a tag corresponding to the language you are using (c#?).

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I made a question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LotInfo` is an `internal` class, rather than `public`, because you've not specified any modifier for it.

But then you construct a type `Dictionary<int, LotInfo>` and try to expose it via a `public` field (`dicLotDatabase`) on a `public` type (`LotInfoDatabase`). Making `LotInfo` `public` would be one way to fix this problem, but I'm not sure if it's what you want to do.

Comment: omg, i really made that silly mistake, now it works perfectly. Thanks for the teaching.